# C# How do I get the path to the System assembly

Tags: c#

I need to find the assembly path of `System.dll` in my c# code to execute a c# file with roslyn in my code.

```
typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location
```

Returns `"C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.Net\\assembly\\GAC_MSIL\\System.Core\\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\\System.Core.dll"` which is great because I need the `System.Core.dll`, but I also need `System.dll`

But I can't seem to find a type that is contained in `System.dll`

Comment: sounds like an x-y problem - care to share why you need this information?

Comment: I'm compiling a c# file with CSharpCompilation and I want to pass references to assemblies such as System

Comment: Not sure why `object` gives you the path of System.Core.dll.  Are you sure that's right?

Comment: @madreflection you are rigth, I meant to write Enumerable

Comment: Curious, though... if you need a reference to it, wouldn't you already know what type(s) you needed from it?

Comment: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory()`

Comment: I note that there is no requirement that there be any `System.DLL` available when compiling a C# assembly. **System.DLL is a C# assembly** and obviously it has to be compiled in a world where it does not already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Uri` is an example of a type in the System assembly.

Quick PowerShell confirmation:

```bsh
[System.Uri].Assembly.Location
```

Comment: thats implementation dependent.

Comment: it could change between versions.

Comment: @DanielA.White  It will definitely break if this particular implementation detail changes but that's technical debt for ya. :s

Comment: To Daniel A. White's point, `System.Uri` is in System.Private.Uri.dll in .NET Core 2.1, for example, and System.dll is nothing but forwarded types.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio (2017 at least), right-click on the project reference to `System` and then click on 'View in Object Browser'.

Try `System.Uri` — as it happens, `System.dll` doesn't contain what one might reasonably assume it contains. I'm sure there was actual thought went into what goes where. Or not. For example:

[image: System.dll contents]

Answer (score 0):

You need to walk through the dependencies tree using `typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`, and their dependencies and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use dotPeek. It's free and you can see metadata of a dll file.
[Screenshot from dotPeek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sotK9.jpg)

Now you can see that you can use for example `FileStyleUriParser`.

```
var path = typeof(FileStyleUriParser).Assembly.Location;
```

And voila, you have path to System.dll.

Also you can use Visual Studio object browser. `View -> Object Browser` or `Ctrl + Alt + J` and you achieve that same result.